# Rails: incrementing attribute from a model, upon creation of an instance from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, orm, relational-database

Our Rails app works with the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end
```

And here are our migrations:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      ...
      t.integer :total_calendar_count
      t.integer :owned_calendar_count

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateAdministrations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :administrations do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :role

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateCalendars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :calendars do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

When a new @calendar is created, we need to increment `:total_calendar_count` and `:owner_calendar_count` by one in the User table.

We tried this in the CalendarsController:

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @calendar = current_user.calendars.create(calendar_params)
    current_user.total_calendar_count += 1
    current_user.owned_calendar_count += 1
    current_user.administrations.find_by(calendar_id: @calendar.id).update(role: 'Creator')
    ...
  end
```

But it does not seem to update `:total_calendar_count` and `:owner_calendar_count` by one in the User table.

Are we missing a step here? Should we use an update action instead?

Comment: have a google of `Rails counter_cache` - which might do this for you.

Comment: Are you forgetting to save `current_user` after you increment the counts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem in your code is that you don't then save the user.
So you update the counter... but this changes it on the local instance... and then after the controller action is done the change you made just disappears.

if you wanted to keep your code the way it is, you could do:

```
current_user.save
```

at the end.

but I'd advise you to look into the `counter_cache`, because it's the Rails way.

Also I'll point out that you haven't checked that the calendar successfully got created, before incrementing that counter... it's possible that it could fail a validation and not really have been created... you need to check for that first.

Comment: Thanks Taryn. I did not copy the entire code from the controller, but we do have `current_user.add_calendar_and_role(@calendar.id, 'Creator')`. I also checked counter_cache and it definitely solves our problem regarding incrementing `total_calendar_count`, that we could then simply replace with `calendars_count`. However, we are not sur of how to implement this for `owned_calendar_count`, since we need to only count calendars where `role == "Creator"`. Is there a Rails way to do it too?

Comment: Yes - you can set counter_cache on an association that has conditions.

Comment: Perfect, we'll look into it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have a best idea to solve your problems is as below....

Create a method that will call on the creating of calendar with the callbacks of model like as below...

Add the below inside the calendar model just after the validation and ORM relations

```
after_create :increment_counter


def increment_counter
  calendar_user = self.user
  calendar_user.update(:total_calendar_count += 1, :owned_calendar_count += 1 )
end
```

With the above code you don't need to do anything. It will increment the counter of calendar on every new entry of calendar.

Comment: Thanks. Tried to implement this solution but got the following error: `SyntaxError in UsersController#show
/Users/TXC/code/calendy/app/models/calendar.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting ')' ...update(:total_calendar_count += 1, :owned_calendar_count += ... ... ^ /Users/TXC/code/calendy/app/models/calendar.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`Any idea why?